# Who's on the cover of this issue of Playgirl in 30 Rock?

Tags: props, 30-rock

This still is from *30 Rock* season 3 episode #14, "The Funcooker":

[image]

*30 Rock* is known for its attention to detail and its endless pursuit of even minor jokes and sight gags, so I am willing to bet that the face on the cover of this magazine is some crush of Liz's that is mentioned at some point, either in previous or subsequent episodes. (Is it Astronaut Mike Dexter, by any chance?)

So. Can anyone figure out who's on the cover of this magazine? Is it a reference to anything, within or outside of the *30 Rock* canon? Bonus points: is this a real issue of *Playgirl*?

Comment: The girl looks like the offspring of an unholy liaison between C3PO ans princess Leila.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is a real issue. It is the [December 1979 issue](http://oldmags.com/issue/Playgirl-December-1979) (Special Christmas Issue) of Playgirl magazine, and the person on the cover is **Nick Nolte**.

[image]

Comment: Ah, but what is the joke behind this, I wonder?  (Don't personally like the series so not sure if Nick Nolte himself is a joke of it)

Comment: If I knew, I'd type in :)

Comment: Ah, interesting! In the episode, Liz mentions her issues of Playgirl from the early eighties. December 1979 just barely fails to make the cut :)

Comment: If anyone has any examples of Nick Nolte being a bit in 30 Rock, please add them to Mehper's excellent answer!

Comment: well my first guess was that it was a reference to Star Wars, but the first movie came out in 1977, not 1979.

Comment: @DForck42 Well, The Empire Strikes Back was released 21 May 1980 so there's that.

Comment: Nick Nolte was once up for the role of Han Solo, but missed out on it - maybe that is the connection.